# How to rename network interface in 15.10?

Tags: networking

I decided to do a clean install of 15.10, and as a result, need to reinstall MATLAB. MATLAB licenses are tied to the the eth0 hardware address.

My Ethernet card is listed as enp1s0, and I need to rename it to eth0. only lo is listed in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` does not exist, so I'm unsure where to start.

Comment: You can define a `udev` rule to rename the interface as `eth0`..lets say the MAC address of the interface is `xx:XX:xx:YY:yy:ZZ` then you can create a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` e.g. `99-rename-net.rules` and put `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:XX:xx:YY:yy:ZZ", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"` in the file..if you don't know the MAC address then you can get it from `/sys/class/net/enp1so/address` file..

Comment: @heemayl if you added that comment as an answer, then people could comment on it more easily and discuss why it seems to work for some people and not for others. Hugs!

Comment: @heemayl's answer in the comment above did not work for me, on a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 install.

Comment: In the above, @jdnz suggested using systemd's ```.link``` files, but some others suggested that this did not work for them. It most likely did not work because [after editing the link files the initramfs must be updated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397737/why-is-my-systemd-link-file-being-ignored). So, follow @jndz's answer first, and then follow the answer I linked above.

Answer (score 29):

My solution to this was to create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-rename-network.rules` with the content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: This DID work for me on Ubuntu 15.10 (unlike higher-voted answers and comments on the question)

Comment: @steve-mohan This is the right answer and should be marked as correct.

Comment: This works indeed as of 16.04.

Comment: Since this is the top answer -- just want to note what actually worked for me .. had to change a grub config and regenerate the boot command so to disable renaming of the network interfaces as described here: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/mini-howtos/change-default-network-name-ens33-to-old-eth0-on-ubuntu-16-04.html

Comment: Worked for me in 16.04. ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff needed to be replaced with the MAC address.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and adding files to `/etc/udev/rules.d/` did not help. The issue seems to be in the use of Predictable Network Interface Names as described [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). To create your own manual naming scheme, i.e., to name your device "eth0" for MATLAB, you can create your own `.link` files in `/etc/systemd/network/` as described [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html).

Specifically, I created a file `/etc/systemd/network/10-eth.link` with the contents

```
[Match]
MACAddress=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[Link]
Name=eth0
```

replacing `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` with the MAC address of the device I wanted to change. After reboot the name was as desired.

Comment: This didn't work for me, and I would love to know why.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: This won't work as of 16.04.

Comment: This worked for me on SLES 15 with nmcli.

Answer (score 6):

If for any reason answer suggested by @zab doesnt work for you, you can also disable this naming scheme like it made [here](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/mini-howtos/change-default-network-name-ens33-to-old-eth0-on-ubuntu-16-04.html). But the method proposed by @zab is potentially safer

I just did not include biosdevname=0 to command line argument, it seems to be turned off by default.

Following steps schould be made:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

At the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX add net.ifnames=0

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="[previous parameters] net.ifnames=0"
```

Then generate new grub file:

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

At the end reboot system.

Comment: Could you please elaborate so that this answer will still be useful if that link is not available in the future?

Comment: @Zanna That's done

Comment: After countless attempts at everything on the entire internet, this is what fixed ethernet for me. My situation (for Google Searches in the future) was no ethernet after installing Linux Mint (or Ubuntu) via Serva / PXE because the stupid network adapter uses predictable network interface name instead of eth0.  The instructions were found here: http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/mini-howtos/change-default-network-name-ens33-to-old-eth0-on-ubuntu-16-04.html

Comment: As of today (with all updates installed) this works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue running  16.04 Server (minimal) on a raspberry pi 3 and none of the posted answers helped. What solved the problem was disabling Predictable Network Interface Names as descripbed here: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

by running this command:

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

Comment: **This is the definitive way to revert to the old behavior, but** the other solutions here will allow better control over which exact interface has what name, as opposed to letting the numbering change e.g. when your laptop is docked vs undocked.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on 16.04 server as eno1 was showing when I did `ifconfig -a`.  I had to bring up the interface as `ifconfig eno1 up` then I did the following:

```
vi /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: Does this change the name immediately, or only after a reboot?

Comment: This last item, 10-network.rules is what worked for me using Ubuntu-18 on Mac Parallels VM, otherwise I had an "enp0s5" name for ETH0