# How to change the name of the network interface

Tags: networking, 18.04, hardware, interface

I have two WiFi adapters on my laptop, a USB dongle and the builtin one. I just want to change the name of the interface to more friendly name. e.g `wlp8s0` to `BuiltIn` or `wlx0022c0789668` to `D-Link` like the screen shot below.

I'm using Kubuntu [18.04](/questions/tagged/18.04) and the suggested similar questions are for 15.04 and there is no any clear description on how to perform that.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename network interface in 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689501/)