# eth0 is not configured

Tags: networking

I don't have configured eth0; how can I do this?

```
enp63s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::21a:4bff:fe48:fc4c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:1a:4b:48:fc:4c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 61753  bytes 81875136 (81.8 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 30912  bytes 3167436 (3.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 19  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 2052  bytes 251314 (251.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2052  bytes 251314 (251.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp


nameserver 127.0.11
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: @user535733 That's incorrect. Typically desktop installations use NetworkManager, and server installations use netplan. And `/etc/network/interfaces` is NM speak.

Comment: You don't say what version of Ubuntu you're using. You incorrectly modified /etc/network/interfaces. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Is this a desktop or server installation?

Answer (score 2):

This is known as [Predictable Network Interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) naming and is part of [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), to which Ubuntu has been transitioning as of version 15.04.

In case you decide to revert back to the other version of naming:

[How to rename network interface in 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689501/how-to-rename-network-interface-in-15-10)