# How to rename a network interface in 20.04

Tags: networking

My main ethernet interface is called `enp2s0`, but some software requires me to name it to `eth0`.

How can I rename it?

I tried creating `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-rename-network.rules` (as per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689501/how-to-rename-network-interface-in-15-10)), creating `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rule` and editing `/etc/network/interfaces`.

The contents of `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-rename-network.rules` were:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", NAME="eth0"
```

with ff:ff...:ff replaced with the mac address of `enp2s0`.

Comment: In your research, did you look at [this resource](https://sulli.blog/ubuntu-20-04-change-network-interface-name/)

Comment: I just tried this, with no success - the network went down when trying `sudo netplan try`

Comment: No software / applications should need to know the network interface name ... what sw are you using ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using netplan which is the default these days.
File `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` file.

Find the target devices mac/hw address  using the lshw command:

```
lshw -C network
```

You'll see some output which looks like:

```
root@ys:/etc# lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: eth0
       serial: dc:a6:32:e8:23:19
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=5.8.0-1015-raspi duplex=full ip=192.168.0.112 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

So then you take the serial

```
dc:a6:32:e8:23:19
```

*Note the set-name option.*

This works for the wifi section as well.

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: <YOUR MAC ID HERE>
            set-name: eth0
```

Then then to test this config run.

```
sudo netplan try
```

When your happy with it

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: Network interface went down after creating this file with this content.

Comment: Did you replace <MAC 'eth0' [ID1]> with your devices hardware address?

Comment: If you do ip addr it will list all the devices and part of that output will be your mac id..
e.g. link/ether dc:a6:32:e8:23:19

Comment: That's how netplan identifies the device to rename..
Then run..

sudo netplan apply

Comment: I've added more details to the answer to help you..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the further explanation, I had not replaced `<MAC 'eth0' [ID1]>` with the actual mac address! It is working now :)

Comment: No problem glad to have helped..

Comment: For me the the Network interface went missing after trying correct configuration with `netplan try`. Came back when I executed `netplan apply` & worked.

Answer (score 6):

Open "etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml" with any text editor
and copy paste text from down bolow and don't forget to paste your own "mac addresses"

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
  network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fc:15:b4:bn:34:g5
            set-name: eth0
        wlan0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 00:22:34:f4:d3:45
            set-name: wlan0
```

and save the file after that use

```
netplan try

netplan apply
```

Comment: this just adds a global NetworkManager connection with the set-name value, does not change the product name of the interface

Answer (score 0):

The arm64 version of Focal Fossa I have does not have netplan, it uses nmcli, and changing the kernel command line is difficult. I was able to create `/etc/udev/rules.d/73-special-net-names.rules` (which on this install overrides `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/73-special-net-names.rules`) to change the name of a usb attached ethernet port (after using `lsusb` to find the id 413c:a102) by adding:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="a102", NAME="eth0"
```

and then rebooting.

Comment: Alternately you could just install the netplan package netplan.io its a lot more friendly then Netplan will do all the hard work for you.