# How can I interchange my ethernet name from eth2 to eth1

Tags: networking, 20.04

I am trying to change the eth2 name to change with eth1. I have tried with /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules, but it takes no effect after reboot.
I am using ubuntu 20.04
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSRfr.png)

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1317043/1222991) will walk you through the process 

Comment: Sorry @matigo but it is not working for me. any other steps you have with