# Ubuntu 16.04 Complicated Interface Names

Tags: grub2, 16.04, systemd, interface, sysfs

I'm trying to figure out how to restore the simple interface names in Ubuntu 16.04. I.e. `enp3s0` renamed to `eth0`.

- I have tried to modify the GRUB configuration. I have tried editing `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules`, but both methods did nothing for me.
  Help is greatly appreciated.

  `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules`: (I hid the mac address names.)

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX″,KERNEL=="enp0s0″, NAME="eth0″
  SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX″,KERNEL=="wlx02c5c1866772″, NAME="wlan0″
  ```
- And I changed this line in the GRUB configuration (`/etc/default/grub`) ...

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
  ```

  to look like this:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=1"
  ```

Comment: Check this out https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/. Looks complicated indeed.

Comment: Is this a virtualbox or real machine? If it is real what's the brand/model? Are you running in UEFI mode or BIOS legacy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on VBox with Ubuntu 16.04, `enp0s3` → `eth0`

### Option 1:

1. Override udev rule

   ```
   sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
   ```
2. Update RAMDisk

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

### Option 2:

1. Create a systemd link file

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/systemd/network/10-eth.link
   ```
2. Let's define name related to MAC: (There are many options, see the linked reference)

   ```
   [Match]
   MACAddress=08:00:27:de:dd:4c

   [Link]
   Name=eth0
   ```
3. Update RAMDisk

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

### Option 3:

1. Add `net.ifnames=0` to boot parameters

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash net.ifnames=0"
   ```
2. Update grub

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

**Reference:** [systemd: Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/), Thanks @mikewhatever .

Comment: Option 2 appears to be the most resilient to upgrades because it only makes changes to the network devices you're concerned about.  Option 1 and 3 both have side-effects that may change other devices/interfaces.  However, I can't seem to get option 2 to work after a 14.04.3 to 16.04 upgrade. I may be missing a systemd service.  `dmesg` lists the interfaces being renamed from ethX to enpXsY but not back again so I suspect a systemd service is needed to be enable for option2 to work.   To be clear, I'm doing option 2 in isolation. Do you have any idea what service is required for option 2?

Comment: @tudor, I think this is the related `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`, seems systemd using a udev rule actually as explained here (`man systemd.link`) https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html . and the next seems also related for boot parameter option3: `/lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules`

Comment: I've corrected Option 2 cause it doesn't work the way you thought it did. Try using different name, say, eth5 and you'll realise that `eth0` is just default name you get if you don't run `update-initramfs -u`