# How to change naming scheme for network interfaces of an already installed Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet, udev, systemd

I want to change naming scheme for network interfaces for the classic one (eth0, eth1, etc). Is it possible to an already installed Ubuntu 16.04 machine?

Comment: You may try option2 here https://askubuntu.com/a/788343/26246 . using same solution as in mattias' answer should work but may need to override `80-net-setup-link.rules`  as in option1. Reference: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: Could you try solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/704361/why-is-my-network-interface-named-enp0s25-instead-of-eth0 . may be a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, edit the following file with your favorite editor ([vi](http://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/) for example)

```
vi /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Comment: On my 16.04 system, `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules ` does not exist.  How about yours, @mattias?

Comment: Wops, assumption is the mother of all f.... It exists in Ubuntu 14.0.4 so I just assumed the same for 16.04.