# Why do my devices disappear?

Tags: drivers, wireless

I needed to add a wifi-USB module to my RPi 3. Originally, there is a wired NIC built in it. So, I could find 'eth0' and 'lo' from response of 'ifconfig' command. I installed wifi driver by 'apt-get install firmware-realtek' and then I can see wlan0 appearing at 'ifconfig'. The problem is then that I couldn't find IP address for wlan0 in resposne list of ifconfig.

After some effort of having wlan0 showing IP address, I found 'eth0' and 'wlan0' vanished unexpectedly. 
It shows '`error fetching interface information: Device not found`' for command "`ifconfig wlan0`" How can I recover them? Before I found the trouble, I already made `wlan0` appearing at response of `ifconfig`. I also found all Wifi APs at my office shown at response of iwlist.

I used command '`systemctl status networking.service`', I got response of
....

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neworking.service: enabled: vendor preset:enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-06-04 22:33:12 BST: 1h 21min agon
   Docs:man: interfaces(5)
Process: 844 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

....

I can't remember what I did cause such trouble.
What can I do to make `eth0` and `wlan0` back again?

Comment: When I used command 'ifconfig -a', I got

enxb827eb63f456: flags=1098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
      ether b8:27:......
      .....
lo: flags=.....

wlx08bcac028337: flags=....
....

The strange is that there are two devices: enxxxx and wlxxxx which should be eth0 and wlan0 respectively instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my mistake. The two devices, eth0 and wlan0, didn't disappear. They were just renamed by raspi-config as enxxxxxxxxxxxx and wlwwwwwwwwwwww; where xxxx* and www* are their MAC addresses respectively. I mistook them as wrong devices. I used the method at [renaming network interface in Ubuntu 16.04 with systemd fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783457/renaming-network-interface-in-ubuntu-16-04-with-systemd-fails) to rename them back to eth0 and wlan0.