# Network Interfaces name Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04

I try to change my Network Interface Name to the old style eth0, eth1 like [with this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04/792627#792627):

via this line in grub config it seems to work.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

I changed this line unfortunately I have 2 Network ports, and by random the eth0 port swaps on system boot. What helps?

assigning the mac adress in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` helps problem is I have to generically write this file for many computers and we have boards where we need to make sure that a defined port helps e.g. the left one.

Comment: You could possibly script the rewriting of the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file. How do you currently identify which network card you want to use from within Ubuntu?

Comment: in ubuntu 12 I used e.g. always the right hand port with eth0. In Ubuntu 12/14 it did not swap on system boot.

Comment: Do they have same hardware (motherboard)?

Comment: unfortunately not