# Eth0 on my ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, interface

I am working on a networking project that requires me to have eth0 interface.
On doing an ifconfig this is what I see.

```
anuvrattiku@anuvrattiku-Inspiron-13-7368:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:14335 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14335 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:1743272 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:1743272 (1.7 MB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:07:15:23:f2:f8  
      inet addr:192.168.0.16  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5fff:b2a0:e985:b475/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2601:646:8501:c10:f91:29b7:c0fd:3ebb/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:315519 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:64909 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:391223230 (391.2 MB)  TX bytes:9020230 (9.0 MB)
```

Is there any way to get eth0 up. I tried adding eth0 to the /etc/network/interfaces file but it is not working.

Here is the error.

```
[BroControl] > start
starting bro (was crashed) ...
bro terminated immediately after starting; check output with "diag"
[BroControl] > diag
[bro]

Bro 2.4.1
Linux 4.4.0-36-generic


==== No reporter.log

==== stderr.log
fatal error: problem with interface eth0 (eth0: SIOCETHTOOL(ETHTOOL_GET_TS_INFO) ioctl failed: No such device)

==== stdout.log
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited

==== .cmdline
-i eth0 -U .status -p broctl -p broctl-live -p standalone -p local -p bro local.bro broctl broctl/standalone broctl/auto
```

Is there any workaround here.

Comment: The eth0 is the name of an ethernet adapter.  What is the name and brand of your ethernet adapter?  Will you edit your question and add the output of this command: `sudo lshw -C netwrok`

Comment: I think it is: `sudo lshw -C network`  .

Comment: You might find this interesting. http://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: `ethX` are old names (kernel V2?). Modern kernels use the [Consistent Network Device Naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Network_Device_Naming). For your project, you can possibly use the Wifi interface (wlp*) instead. To get an Ethernet interface you need to have a hardware one (or in a VM since the newtworking is usually an emulated Ethernet). In 2020, I would be wary of any software (or tutorial)  that insist on a network interface called `eth0`, there may be other outdated things/incompatibilities...

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is happening because you don't have an `eth0` interface.  You do have a `wlp1s0` interface.  You'll have to edit the program to use the device you have (or install a new hardware device).

Looking at the github site there is a sample `node.cfg` file where this is configured.

Change the line in the `node.cfg` file:

Change from:

```
[bro]
type=standalone
host=localhost
interface=eth0
```

Change to:

```
[bro]
type=standalone
host=localhost
interface=wlp1s0
```