# Network Interface names change every reboot

Tags: networking

Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 Server.  Setup netplan config.  However netplan config stops working after a reboot because the interface names change each time for some reason.  Setup netplan config to match on mac address and set name, but this still does not work because interface name changes every reboot.

Tried setting grub back to old interface naming convention (eth0) but did not work.  Tried changing netplan config to reflect interface names as (ens0) also did not work.

Interface names that change are random and different each reboot.

dmesg | grep eth output

```
[    9.704345] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(629133-001) rev 5719001] (PCI Express) MAC address ac:16:2d:8c:83:40
[    9.747819] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5719C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[    9.747821] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[    9.747824] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[    9.772054] tg3 0000:03:00.1 eth1: Tigon3 [partno(629133-001) rev 5719001] (PCI Express) MAC address ac:16:2d:8c:83:41
[    9.887044] tg3 0000:03:00.1 eth1: attached PHY is 5719C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[    9.922968] tg3 0000:03:00.1 eth1: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[    9.960541] tg3 0000:03:00.1 eth1: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   10.027843] tg3 0000:03:00.2 eth2: Tigon3 [partno(629133-001) rev 5719001] (PCI Express) MAC address ac:16:2d:8c:83:42
[   10.066251] tg3 0000:03:00.2 eth2: attached PHY is 5719C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[   10.105881] tg3 0000:03:00.2 eth2: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[   10.145704] tg3 0000:03:00.2 eth2: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   10.214958] tg3 0000:03:00.3 eth3: Tigon3 [partno(629133-001) rev 5719001] (PCI Express) MAC address ac:16:2d:8c:83:43
[   10.290362] tg3 0000:03:00.3 eth3: attached PHY is 5719C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[   10.290364] tg3 0000:03:00.3 eth3: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[   10.290366] tg3 0000:03:00.3 eth3: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   10.660995] tg3 0000:03:00.1 eno2: renamed from eth1
[   11.045599] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[   12.513784] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: RTL8168c/8111c, 00:e0:4c:69:58:ab, XID 3c4, IRQ 126
[   12.514210] tg3 0000:03:00.3 eno4: renamed from eth3
[   12.673906] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 6128 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   12.902002] tg3 0000:03:00.2 eno3: renamed from eth2
[   14.432154] r8169 0000:0a:00.0 eth1: RTL8168c/8111c, 00:e0:4c:69:58:ac, XID 3c4, IRQ 127
[   14.732638] r8169 0000:0a:00.0 eth1: jumbo features [frames: 6128 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   14.865814] r8169 0000:0b:00.0 eth2: RTL8168c/8111c, 00:e0:4c:69:58:ad, XID 3c4, IRQ 128
[   14.865819] r8169 0000:0b:00.0 eth2: jumbo features [frames: 6128 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   14.877849] r8169 0000:0c:00.0 eth3: RTL8168c/8111c, 00:e0:4c:69:58:ae, XID 3c4, IRQ 129
[   14.877857] r8169 0000:0c:00.0 eth3: jumbo features [frames: 6128 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   14.885379] r8169 0000:0b:00.0 ens2: renamed from eth2
[   19.550328] r8169 0000:0a:00.0 ens7: renamed from eth1
[   19.585651] r8169 0000:0c:00.0 ens5: renamed from eth3
[   19.701789] r8169 0000:09:00.0 ens8: renamed from eth0
```

cat /etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
Everything I have tried does not resolve.
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
#This is the network config written by ''
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      match:
        macaddress: ac:16:2d:8c:83:40
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
      set-name: eth1
    eth2:
      match:
        macaddress: ac:16:2d:8c:83:41
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      set-name: eth2
    eth3:
      match:
        macaddress: ac:16:2d:8c:83:42
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      set-name: eth3
    eth4:
      match:
        macaddress: ac:16:2d:8c:83:43
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      set-name: eth4
    eth5:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:e0:4c:69:58:ae
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
      set-name: eth5
    eth6:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:e0:4c:69:58:ad
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      set-name: eth6
    eth7:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:e0:4c:69:58:ac
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      set-name: eth7
    eth8:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:e0:4c:69:58:ab
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      set-name: eth8
  bonds:
    bond-lan:
      interfaces: [eth1, eth5]
      addresses: # [my ip address]
      gateway4: # my gateway
      nameservers:
        search: # [my domain]
        addresses: # [my name servers]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
```

/etc/network/interfaces is empty.  the file is there, but contains nothing

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth4
       version: 01
       serial: ac:16:2d:8c:83:40
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5719-v1.31 NCSI v1.1.15.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:57 memory:f67f0000-f67fffff memory:f67e0000-f67effff memory:f67d0000-f67dffff memory:f4000000-f401ffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: eth5
       version: 01
       serial: ac:16:2d:8c:83:41
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5719-v1.31 NCSI v1.1.15.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:129 memory:f67c0000-f67cffff memory:f67b0000-f67bffff memory:f67a0000-f67affff memory:f4020000-f403ffff
  *-network:2 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
       logical name: eth6
       version: 01
       serial: ac:16:2d:8c:83:42
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5719-v1.31 NCSI v1.1.15.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:57 memory:f6790000-f679ffff memory:f6780000-f678ffff memory:f6770000-f677ffff memory:f4040000-f405ffff
  *-network:3 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.3
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.3
       logical name: eth7
       version: 01
       serial: ac:16:2d:8c:83:43
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5719-v1.31 NCSI v1.1.15.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:129 memory:f6760000-f676ffff memory:f6750000-f675ffff memory:f6740000-f674ffff memory:f4060000-f407ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth8
       version: 02
       serial: 00:e0:4c:69:58:ab
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full ip=10.29.250.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:39 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:f7cf0000-f7cf0fff memory:f68f0000-f68fffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 02
       serial: 00:e0:4c:69:58:ac
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:24 ioport:7000(size=256) memory:f7df0000-f7df0fff memory:f69f0000-f69fffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: eth2
       version: 02
       serial: 00:e0:4c:69:58:ad
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:42 ioport:8000(size=256) memory:f7ef0000-f7ef0fff memory:f6af0000-f6afffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: eth3
       version: 02
       serial: 00:e0:4c:69:58:ae
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:38 ioport:9000(size=256) memory:f7ff0000-f7ff0fff memory:f6bf0000-f6bfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: bond-lan
       serial: fa:c7:fe:9b:92:cc
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bonding driverversion=3.7.1 firmware=2 ip=10.30.142.69 link=no master=yes multicast=yes
```

After updating grub file to reflect GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0" and starting interface names at eth0, names stayed per netplan config file for 3 reboots then the MAC Addresses started moving between interface names preventing network connection from establishing.  I decided to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch and, this time, with a live network connection and enabled all interfaces for dhcp.  Below are the netplan config file and interfaces.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
    eno3:
      dhcp4: true
    eno4:
      dhcp4: true
    ens2:
      dhcp4: true
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
    eth2:
      dhcp4: true
    eth3:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.29.250.18/29 brd 10.29.250.23 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 3317sec preferred_lft 3317sec
    inet6 fe80::ae16:2dff:fe8c:8340/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eno3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eno4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: ens2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: eth2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: eth3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I then proceeded to change my config file to how I wanted it.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
    eno3:
      dhcp4: true
    eno4:
      dhcp4: true
    ens2:
      dhcp4: true
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
    eth2:
      dhcp4: true
    eth3:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
  bonds:
    bond-lan:
      interfaces: [eno1, eth3]
      addresses: [ipaddress]
      gateway4: gatewayip
      nameservers:
        search: [domain]
        addresses: [name-serversip]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup 
  version: 2
```

Things were good for 2 reboots and then this

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond-lan state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 3a:88:89:a5:3f:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    5: ens2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    6: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.29.250.21/29 brd 10.29.250.23 scope global dynamic eno2
           valid_lft 3463sec preferred_lft 3463sec
        inet6 fe80::ae16:2dff:fe8c:8341/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    7: eth5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 2e:da:df:ac:3b:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    8: eno3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    9: eno4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: bond-lan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:88:89:a5:3f:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.30.142.69/24 brd 10.30.142.255 scope global bond-lan
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3888:89ff:fea5:3f7e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

1. eth0 became eth1
2. ens2 had MAC 58:ac but now has MAC 58:ad
3. eth2 had MAC 58:ad but now has MAC 58:ac
4. eth3 had MAC 00:e0:4c:69:58:ae and now has disappeared and I have a new
   interface eth5 and a completely new MAC of 2e:da:df:ac:3b:3e, but the physical
   interface is the same.

Another reboot later, and it changes again

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond-lan state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:88:89:a5:3f:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.29.250.21/29 brd 10.29.250.23 scope global dynamic eno2
       valid_lft 3406sec preferred_lft 3406sec
    inet6 fe80::ae16:2dff:fe8c:8341/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ens2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:69:58:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: eno3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:da:df:ac:3b:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: eno4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:16:2d:8c:83:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: bond-lan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:88:89:a5:3f:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.30.142.69/24 brd 10.30.142.255 scope global bond-lan
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3888:89ff:fea5:3f7e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The physical interfaces of the motherboard appear to be holding fine and it seems the problem is only occurring on the PCI slot interfaces.  At this point I'm at the conclusion there is something wrong with the PCI network card and am looking for a replacement.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/default/grub` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: I've updated the question.  apologies if not done correctly....first time posting here.  The /etc/network/interfaces file is there, but doesn't contain anything.  I believe at one point it only contained the lo0 interface.  I had started the rollback process of moving away from netplan and back to ifupdown but decided to pose the question before i got to far.  ifupdown was installed but has been uninstalled since.

Appreciate your assistance!

Comment: I've put together an incomplete answer. Do it, and update your `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: How many ethernet ports on your motherboard? How many ethernet cards in slots? How many ports per slot?

Comment: @heynnema I can't believe I overlooked that in /etc/default/grub...smh.  sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes.  Making changes now and will update question after. And no, i don't have the # in my bond interface, just blanked it out and put those in as comments for post. There are 4 ethernet ports on motherboard and 1 ethernet card in slot with 4 ports.

Comment: In real life, I'd remove the "net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0" and use the names provided by the system.

Comment: @heynnema   I updated my question with new output of sudo lshw -C network after making the change to the grub file.  All interfaces came up as I was hoping with correct names.  However after another reboot, eth1 got it's name changed to eth0, despite what is set in the netplan config file.  Would it be best to start my naming convention with eth0 and go from there or should that not matter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110142/discussion-between-boomsfib-and-heynnema).

Comment: @heynnema  Apologies.  I just now got the chance to sign on today and update.  So last night I did as you suggested and set grub file to just "net.ifnames=0" and started interface naming at eth0.  This worked, but only for 3 reboots.  After the 3rd reboot, the names stayed the same but the MAC Addresses started moving between the names.  I  then decided that since this was a fresh install, that it would be best to just start from scratch and re-install Ubuntu. I enabled all interfaces for DHCP during install as to get assigned names.  But issue seems to continue.  Updating question

Comment: Remove the Realtek PCI card and reset your .yaml for just the 4 motherboard ports  as eth0-3 along with the appropriate MAC address. Reboot a bunch of times and see if the ethernet ports work as expected.

Comment: I see that you're coming to the same conclusion as me. It's funny that the PCI card came up as ens2, eth0, eth2, and eth3. Check for a firmware update for the card. Also make sure it's in an appropriate speed PCI slot. You might need to view speed settings in the BIOS.

Comment: Any final conclusions?

Comment: @heynnema I ended up pulling the Realtek out.  Everything is stable now.  I talked to our server guys and they said the Realtek i pulled from the old server (and I mean OLD) probably isn't compatible and they have some HP network cards for the Gen 8 Proliant server that are.  So I'll grab that from them sometime and put it in and we'll see what happens.  Thanks for all your help and knowledge.

Comment: see this page [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/826325/how-to-revert-usb-wifi-interface-name-from-wlxxxxxxxxxxxxx-to-wlanx) for a good explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/etc/default/grub` is incorrect.

`sudo pico /etc/default/grub`

This line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0""
```

Should look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

However, in real life, I'd recommend this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

`sudo lshw -C network` # edit this update into your question

**Update #1:**

There are 4 ethernet ports on motherboard and 1 ethernet card in slot with 4 ports.

It appears that the Realtek PCI card is not working properly, or it's in the wrong speed slot, or the BIOS has set the wrong speed for that slot. Also check for firmware updates for the card.