# How do I configure this interface for a static address?

Tags: networking

I cannot configure `enp2s0` interface despite going through forum and many instruction pages. The interface does not show ip address in configuration though the interface is UP.

Cable is working. Tested on other devices, and with tester.

These are the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
#the loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopb

auto enp2s0

iface enp2s0 int static
address 192.168.1.10
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255

iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

I have already tried restarting the Network Manager and bringing the interface down and back up again. What else do I need to do?

Comment: (1) you have a typo (`int` should be `inet`) (2) you can't define an interface as both `static` and `dhcp` (3) if this is a desktop OS you should probably be using the network-manager GUI instead

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`? Add it to your question please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Network Interfaces name Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I had to place a config file for the static IP into /etc/network/interfaces.d/, just editing /etc/network/interfaces didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Please adjust your file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup -v enp2s0
```

Did you connect?

```
ifconfig
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```