# Changing network interface names or better yet how does it work?

Tags: networking, server

Yes, I found answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04), but by doing so, I lost my static ip setup, not a big deal in itself. My real question, would be how does it work now and why?

Obviously something as change and I presume it's for a good reason, so I'd like to understand how and why since it's not covered yet in the docs (serverquide.pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sudo ifconfig enp2s0 down  
sudo ip link set enp2s0 name eth0  
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Answer from **michel_04** found here : https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2007521

I actually also had to modify `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: There's an in-line citation above the link.