# udev rules are not working after kernel downgrade from 4.4.0-83 to 4.4.0-75

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, udev

We need the persistent network interface names, but after kernel downgrade from 4.4.0-83 to 4.4.0-75 udev rules are not working anymore.

udev rules like below for each interface are already present on the system.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="02:01:02:03:04:05", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0
```

Also we tried giving the following steps 
[Changing Network Interfaces name Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: What's the output of `ifconfig` and the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: looks like this is issue with the Ethernet drivers, after downgrading the kernel devices are not visible