# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs at "stopping raise network interfaces..."

Tags: 16.04, networking, grub2, shutdown, reboot

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and need my first interface to be named `eth0`. That's why I placed the following line in my GRUB config, as suggested by this [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04).

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"
```

The problem is that, after adding this line, Ubuntu hangs at shutdown on

```
"Stopping Raise network interfaces..."
```

Syslog/journalctl do not contain any (useful) messages, so I don't know where to start debugging. I've noticed that when I use

```
systemctl reboot --force
```

to reboot my system, it doesn't hang.

**EDIT**

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:b4:7b:a0
      inet addr:192.168.1.99  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feb4:7ba0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:29046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:20150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:185897012 (185.8 MB)  TX bytes:5042378 (5.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:436 (436.0 B)  TX bytes:436 (436.0 B)
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: And *is* your first interface named eth0? Please edit your question to add the result of: `ifconfig`.

Comment: @chili555 yes, my interface is named eth0 after editing my grub config.

Comment: Is the interface configured in Network Manager or in /etc/network/interfaces? If the latter, may we see the file?

Comment: @chili555 I've added the content of /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Are there any better clues if you do: `sudo -i` followed by: `halt` ? A systemd problem perhaps?

Comment: @chili555 the same thing happens when I do `sudo -i` and `halt`. Do you know which logs I should check to rule out a systemd problem? Where can I start?