# How to force VPN usage on every connection

Tags: scripts, vpn, openvpn, services

I am trying to connect VPN during bootup of my new Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS system.  I am new to Linux.  This is a new installation on an old Gateway laptop built for WindowsXP.  It runs on 1GB RAM and an AMD Turion 64 (1.6Ghz) processor.  I have spent 20-30 hours during the last week scouring tutorials and forums including AskUbuntu, attempting the simple sounding suggestions, re-reading, double-checking my work, etc.  As far as I can tell I have tried every option described... without success.  The three basic options I found are:

1. Use Connection Manager
2. Setup OpenVPN as a service
3. Run a script at bootup

**Option 1**
I used the Nm-connection-manager to install the .ovpn file provided by ExpressVPN.  Then I opened the settings of my LAN connection where I navigated to the General tab and checked the box to `Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection` (I only have the one .ovpn loaded so it selected that option for me by default).  Then I hit save and rebooted. VPN did not connect, but the LAN connection did just fine.  I went back to the Connection Manager and saw that the little check box was now unchecked.  Figuring I might have skipped saving the change, I again checked the box.  Then I clicked SAVE with all my focus and intention.  Reboot. Same story:  No VPN and box is unchecked.

**Option 2:** Here are the steps I took to run VPN as a service

A. Installed OpenVPN.
B. Downloaded the appropriate .ovpn configuration file from my VPN provider (ExpressVPN) and copied it to /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf.
C. Created auth.txt in the same folder, and put my username on the first line and password on the second line.
D. Added ¨auth.txt¨ on the last line of openvpn.conf at the end of the last line which says ¨auth-user-pass¨
E. Ran `$ update-rc.d openvpn default`

Result: Does not connect at bootup

**Option 3:** Steps I took to run a script during bootup:

A. Create a text file in /etc/init.d called script.sh containing:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    expressvpn connect
```

B. Run `$ chmod 755`
C. Run `$ sudo update-rc.d script.sh defaults`

Note: `$ expressvpn connect` is what I currently use to successfully connect to my VPN server.  I currently do this every time I boot the computer.
Result: I see that script.sh shows up as bright green alongside the other contents of init.d, but the VPN does not connect during bootup.

Overall conclusion: I am not confident that any scripts in /etc/init.d are being run at bootup.  I tried running other scripts at bootup without success.

If you have read all of this you may be some sort of saint.  I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why you dismiss Option 1. Your stated requirement is to connect during boot, and by definition that can't be to a new connection.  Are you actually asking "How to force VPN usage on every connection" and the "bootup" part is misleading?

Comment: I have now changed the wording of the question per your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, I did that try option 1 as well, and it doesnt work either.  I will add those details as well.

Comment: Hmm, Option 1 ticking the box "automatically connect to VPN when using this connection" has always worked for me.  I understand that does not meet your needs though since it does not cover new connections.

Now that it's clarified, I have found a couple of other people on the site asking for a similar thing, but unfortunately all the questions are old and don't have accepted answers. Such as https://askubuntu.com/q/160048/243321 https://askubuntu.com/q/47048/243321 https://askubuntu.com/q/26793/243321

Comment: These links you provided are certainly on topic.  They seem a little over my head.  It seems like they include variables that might be easy for a more experienced user to solve.  Am I trying to do something unusual?   I assume that all Ubuntu users using a VPN would want their computers to do the same thing.    Right?

Comment: I think a user who normally used a few connections would just tick the box in Network Manager "automatically connect to VPN when using this connection" on those connections. (My interest in this is that I set up my own OpenVPN server and I'm still in the learning mode, I am no expert).  If there is a way to *force any new connection to use the VPN without the user taking any action* I don't know what it would be, but I am interested in the topic.

Comment: I am trying your #2 now... it might just be your type but it only ran for me with E. Ran $ sudo update-rc.d openvpn defaults   , note the defaults not default.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a decent solution by accident:

```
expressvpn autoconnect true
```

I dont know why it doesnt install that way by default.

Comment: my nordvpn sometimes works that way, and sometimes does not... the #2 solution above  did not work, and "it is the ubuntu way"  now on reboots brings up login/pass field for ubuntu even though I have autologin set, and lo and behold, even logs me in properly if I put rubbish username/password into it. tar babies.