# Prevent device address from changing

Tags: networking, virtualization

Is there a way to stop device addresses from changing? By device address, I am referring to the address displayed by `lspci`. This is used for addressing all sorts of devices, including network interfaces and graphics cards. 
For example, according to `lspci` my network device is at `0d:00.0`. If I remove my PCI-E USB card from the computer, the device is not at `0c:00.0`. This changes the network port from `enp13s0` to `enp12s0`, which breaks the static IP setup and prevents the network from coming up during boot. I have to manually edit the network configuration and update the address.
This wouldn't be that big of a deal, especially since I don't add or remove devices very often, but I pass a number of devices through to my VMs and anytime the addresses change I have to make a lot of manual edits.

Is there a way to tell Ubuntu remember that this device should always have this address, and give new devices a later address? I realize that this may be impossible - I don't know how the addresses are determined. Thanks!

Comment: You could switch to the old device naming as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/785442/490838).

Comment: Have you updated the system BIOS?

Comment: If tthe MAC address does not change  you can use a DHCP server that assign IP address according to the ethernet address.

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas, that might help with the network, but I was hoping for a more global solution. I'll update my question to clarify.