# Ubuntu16 startup fault after hardware changes

Tags: startup, hardware, motherboard

I have recently changed the motherboard of this Ubuntu16 system without changing the harddisk. When starting up with the new hardware the following error message displayed. Any help how to troubleshoot this problem?

[image: Startup error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the solution here? http://askubuntu.com/a/817660/658492 only change would be /dev/mapper/tiger--vg-root in the command.

so command would look like

*fsck /dev/mapper/tiger--vg-root -y*

*(mind the -y switch, it will ensure all questions are marked with Answer "yes", if you remove you will have to manually run and answer y for everything asked)*

actually before you do, could you double check if you have connected to disk/controller to the correct slot?

Will wait for your reply :)

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. After starting up, the network service was down and was solved following this other answer.https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: By the way, is this Ubuntu, SSD related problem?

Comment: @ClintonLam Thanks for the relply :) i will have to check if this was Ubuntu SSD related problem :)  lets see