# Systemd mount.nfs fails: Network is unreachable on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mount, systemd, automount, nfs

I've setup an NFS mount in the `/etc/fstab` file of an Ubuntu 16.04.6 machine.
The NFS fails at every boot, I noticed that when the Unity Greeter comes up the network icon on the top right of the screen shows the network as  disconnected, and after 5 seconds it starts the connection process and succeeds. At this point, if I login and run  `mount -a` as a superuser,  it works just fine.
I have tried a bunch of options to force systemd to wait for network, but nothing works...
How do I force NetworkManager to connect before I get to the greeter?
I don't mind the extra boot time delay.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround:
It seems to be related to the way the DHCP works on Ubuntu, so I disabled the [renaming of the Ethernet Interfaces at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04), thus DHCP resolutions was faster.

Comment: The correct solution is to add `_netdev` to the mount options for the nfs filesystem in /etc/fstab.