# Drivers renaming network interfaces - is there a way to prevent it?

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

This is 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

The following is output from `dmesg | grep "renamed from"`.

```
[    6.952855] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    6.973957] e100 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth1
[   22.375269] ath9k_htc 1-2:1.0 wlx6466b31c83ef: renamed from wlan0
```

I am OK with `eno1` and `enp5s0`, but `wlx6466b31c83ef` is getting a little ridiculous. Is there a way to prevent drivers renaming the interfaces?

Comment: can you take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04#answer-767796 and see if this works for you (at least the GRUB part)?

Comment: Oh yes! The GRUB Linux parameter worked.

Comment: also interesting https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/ and https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames

Comment: your 3rd one seems to fall back to "Names incorporating the interfaces's MAC address" so I would assume your BIOS is giving off wrong info (Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided index numbers for on-board devices (example: eno1), 
Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot index numbers (example: ens1), 
Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware (example: enp2s0) come before that.

Comment: Ah, since the now `wlan0` is a USB WiFi adapter, the first criteria it fits is by MAC address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the first part of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04#answer-767796) from another thread:

Step 1: Disable the default Firmware inherited names.

Edit your /etc/default/grub changing the line from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

and, finally run as root:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

and reboot your system.

```
$ sudo reboot
```

(glad it worked)